# WooCommerce strange problem with template files - can't remove DIV from code

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

OK, I was trying everything with no luck, so stackoverflow is my last chance. I have latest version of WordPress with latest version of WooCommerce. On category page I have container div that I can't remove. It's one of the TwentySeventeen div's:

`<div id="primary" class="content-area"><main id="main" class="site-main" role="main">...`

Yes, I build my store on default Twentyseventeen theme but I have re-buid it totally with custom loops, wp_queries ACF plugin custom fields etc. Even name ot this theme is completly different with 90% my won CSS now.

I checked all php files, and I deleted all rows with this DIV, and added my own classes, divs, and Bootstrap DIVS (I use Bootstrap 4). But this div is still there, and ONLY on category page. What is going on?

- Yes I cleared all browser cache
- I was checking this page on other devices
- I was trying to reinstall Wordpress again
- I was trying to activate other theme and then activate my own
- Page has no cache plugins (still dev version, not live page)
- I was trying to deactivate, and activate all plugins (also WooCommerce)
- I Also checked DB for thieese DIV :) - not found
- I don't use any page-builder (only raw code, and ACF PRO plugin)
- I was trying to run debug mode in WP - no errors

The problem is ONLY on category page. I can't remove this container div, and can't find it inside the PHP files. Any ideas?

Comment: I found the solution. The problem was in functions.php ```add_theme_support( 'woocommerce' );``` - removing this line helped. But have no idea why? I was always using this code with WooCommerce.

Comment: But I have to add WooCommerce support in functions.php. Without this code line I can't override Woocommerce template files. So question is still open: why I can see this div on category page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I found the solution! There is also wrapper PHP file in templates catalog: https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/master/templates/global/wrapper-start.php and there is this code! Template file adds there below line:

Line 47

`<div id="primary" class="content-area"><main id="main" class="site-main" role="main">`

Edit -> override -> upload -> done :/

OMG!